# How to define a configuration variable of type multidimensional array in schema.yml?

Tags: 8

How should we define a config variable of type multidimensional array in schema.yml file ?

Something which I figured out from drupal documentation is that we can define either type **mapping** for string value of array or type **sequence** for integer value or string value of array.

But I'm not sure how should we define for our multidimensinal array, as we have to mention the key first and then the type of value which can be assigned to that key.

For reference I'm adding the following e.g code

```
image.style.*:
type: config_entity
label: 'Image style'
mapping:
name:
  type: string
label:
  type: label
  label: 'Label'
effects:
  type: sequence
  sequence:
    type: mapping
    mapping:
      id:
        type: string
      data:
        type: image.effect.[%parent.id]
      weight:
        type: integer
      uuid:
        type: string
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a module which may help you to validate you configuration schema.
https://www.drupal.org/project/config_inspector

Comment: Anything that has specific keys has to be mapping. Sequence is purely for anonymous arrays. If you will have array with specific keys that you do not know upfront, it has to be sequence.

Comment: @IvanJaros So is it necessary to define those upfront keys also?

Comment: In other words, sequence for indexed array, mapping form associative array. Both can be nested.

Comment: can you edit with your array structure?